# R function with expression as parameter for dplyr summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

Okay, this is something that feels like it should be relatively easy, but although I have tried literally dozens of approaches with `quote`, `eval`, `substitute`, `enquote`, `parse`, `summarize_` etc... I haven't gotten it to work. Basically I am trying to calculate something like this - but with a variable expression for the `summarise` argument:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(wt=mean(wt),hp=mean(hp))
```

yielding:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
    cyl       wt        hp   
    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> 
1     4 2.285727  82.63636 
2     6 3.117143 122.28571 
3     8 3.999214 209.21429
```

One of the things I tried was:

```
  x2 <- "wt=mean(wt),hp=mean(hp)"
  mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(eval(parse(text=x2)))
```

yielding:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  <text>:1:12: unexpected ','
1: wt=mean(wt),
```

But leaving away the second argument (`",hp=mean(hp"`) gets you no further:

```
> x2 <- "wt=mean(wt)"
> mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(eval(parse(text=x2)))
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : object 'wt' not found
```

I will spare you all the other things I tried - I am clearly missing something about how expressions get handled in function arguments.

So what is the proper approach here? Keeping in mind I really want something like this in the end:

```
getdf <- function(df,sumarg){
  df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(sumarg)
  df
}
```

Also not sure what kind of tag I should use for this kind of query in the R world. Metaprogramming?

Comment: You probably need to use the standard evaluation version `summarise_`

Comment: One option is using a named vector (or list) like so: `x2 <- c(wt= "mean(wt)", hp = "mean(hp)")` and then `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_(.dots = x2)`

Comment: I tried things with `summarise_` too. This shoudl be easy, right?

Comment: You aren't specifying what part of the expression needs to be dynamic. Did you read `vignette("nse")`? What values do you want `sumarg` to take?

Comment: Ah, `nse` was the term I was looking for. Ideally sumarg would be something like "wt=mean(wt),hp=mean(hp)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For maximum flexibility I would use a `...` argument, capture those dots use `lazyeval`, and then pass to `summarise_`:

```
getdf <- function(df, ...){ 
    df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) 
}
```

Then you can directly do:

```
getdf(mtcars, wt = mean(wt), hp = mean(hp))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 × 3
>     cyl       wt        hp
>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
> 1     4 2.285727  82.63636
> 2     6 3.117143 122.28571
> 3     8 3.999214 209.21429
> ```

One way to do it without `...`, is to pass arguments in a list, although you will need to use formulas or quoting. E.g.:

```
getdf2 <- function(df, args){ 
    dots <- lazyeval::as.lazy_dots(args)
    df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_(.dots = dots) 
}
```

And use as:

```
getdf(mtcars, list(wt = ~mean(wt), hp = ~mean(hp)))
```

or

```
getdf(mtcars, list(wt = "mean(wt)", hp = "mean(hp)"))
```

Comment: Yep, that does it pretty well. Thanks for that. Interesting you beat dd to the punch - pretty impressive.

Comment: Would be curious to know if you could do it with a string? That has some advantages. dots can only be used for one purpose, but you can have a lot of strings.